# MarkerClusterer - associated array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

MarkerClusterer works well with numeric array, but have you tried to use it with object of markers? I mean associated array, because I keep all markers inside this kind of array. Only what comes to my mind is translate associated array to "unusual" array, but this solution looks like strange. I aware that probably is not possible, but maybe someone has workaround for it.

Comment: Note: javascript does not have associative arrays. It has sparse, numerically-indexed arrays, and objects. Somewhat confusingly, arrays may be given properties with `myArray.myProp` or `myArray['myProp']` syntax, neither of which makes an entry in the array itself.

Comment: I know that not have, but "associative array" can be achieved by object.

Comment: Sebastian. Only partially. There's a big difference between javascript arrays and objects; namely that arrays are inherently ordered (elements [0], [1], [2] etc), while an object's properties are completely unordered - they are an "orderless pool".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an array of markers to the MarkerClusterer, or you can add them individually (they don't *have* to be in an array).  Add your markers to the MarkerClusterer as you create them and add them to your "associative" array/object.

See the [addMarker method in the documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)

Comment: Indeed it was the best solution, I should overlook this position in docs. Thank you;)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps API v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html)

```
MarkerClusterer(map:google.maps.Map, opt_markers:Array.<google.maps.Marker>, opt_options:Object)
```

Please note this:
    **opt_markers:Array.**

This means that you should only use an array! According to this, just send your object to normal, numerical, array.

Comment: This is clear, so I prepare converter to array and it works, but I'm wondering if is better option ;) Anyway thank you;)

Comment: I think, that is really most better option :)