# How to use google maps 'Marker Clusterer Plus'

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am using this example:

```js
var locations = [
    ['Location 1 Name', 'New York, NY', 'Location 1 URL'],
    ['Location 2 Name', 'Newark, NJ', 'Location 2 URL'],
    ['Location 3 Name', 'Philadelphia, PA', 'Location 3 URL']
];

var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {


        geocodeAddress(locations, i);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeAddress(locations, i) {
    var title = locations[i][0];
    var address = locations[i][1];
    var url = locations[i][2];
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': locations[i][1]
    },

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                address: address,
                url: url
            })
            infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        } else {
            alert("geocode of " + address + " failed:" + status);
        }
    });
}

function infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var html = "<div><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + address + "<br></div><a href='" + url + "'>View location</a></p></div>";
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: html,
            maxWidth: 350
        });
        iw.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function createMarker(results) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        address: address,
        url: url
    })
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
    return marker;
}
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

I would like to use Marker Clusterer Plus, but I do not know where to put it in this script. Here: [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463131/mapping-multiple-locations-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-and-geocoding-api)

I did not do it. I found it on the internet and it's working, just do not know where to put that blessed Marker Clusterer Plus.

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related questions:

- [Markers Created via JSON Are Not Clustering with Google Maps MarkerClusterer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535626/markers-created-via-json-are-not-clustering-with-google-maps-markerclusterer)
- [MarkerClusterer - associated array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662718/markerclusterer-associated-array)

One option is to create the MarkerClusterer in the global scope, then add the markers to the clusterer in the geocoder callback function when they are created.

in the initialization function:

```
clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
  imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
});
```

then in the geocoder callback:

```
clusterer.addMarker(marker);
```

[image: MarkerClusterer]

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['Location 1 Name', 'New York, NY', 'Location 1 URL'],
  ['Location 2 Name', 'Newark, NJ', 'Location 2 URL'],
  ['Location 3 Name', 'Philadelphia, PA', 'Location 3 URL'],
  ['Location 4 Name', 'Trenton, NJ', 'Location 4 URL'],
  ['Location 5 Name', 'Philadelphia, PA', 'Location 5 URL'],
  ['Location 6 Name', 'Jersey City, NJ', 'Location 6 URL']
];

var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var clusterer;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    geocodeAddress(locations, i);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeAddress(locations, i) {
  var title = locations[i][0];
  var address = locations[i][1];
  var url = locations[i][2];
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': locations[i][1]
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        address: address,
        url: url
      });
      clusterer.addMarker(marker);
      infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    } else {
      alert("geocode of " + address + " failed:" + status);
    }
  });
}

function infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var html = "<div><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + address + "<br></div><a href='" + url + "'>View location</a></p></div>";
    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: html,
      maxWidth: 350
    });
    iw.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```